# Why when I add package paralist into my beamer presentation, enumerate stops working?

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, paralist

I try to simple use `beamer` with `enumerate` and `compactenum` from `paralist`. But when I add `paralist` package in document, `enumerate` just stops working.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{...}
\begin{compactenum}[{\ding{79}}]
\item ...
\item ,,,
\item  ...
\end{compactenum}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

When I do not use `paralist` (and do not use `compactenum`) than the process will end normally. I know `beamer` defines many things and adding `paralist` can make conflicts in definitions but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: In order to use dingbats symbols, don't you need to load a package such as `pifont`?

Comment: Thank you. I try to use it either with and without \dig{}. I am sure it is not only problem.

Comment: You shouldn't load packages which redefines lists in beamer. This will destroy the beamer definitions. Use the commands of beamer to configure your lists.

Comment: If you don't want `paralist` to overwrite `beamer`'s `enumerate` environment, you can pass the package option `oldenum` to `paralist` (similarly `olditem` for `itemize`). This should still allow you to use the `compactenum` environment that `paralist` provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: "because that packages overwrite beamer configuration" (as Ulrike Fischer said).

P.S.: At the end I use following "solution":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pifont}
\setdefaultenum{1)}{a.}{i)}{A}

\begin{document}      
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{"enumerate"}
\begin{compactenum}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{compactenum}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{"itemize"}
\begin{compactenum}[{\ding{81}}]
\item *    
\item *
\end{compactenum}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

But surely it will be more clear to listen to Ulrike Fischer: "Use the commands of beamer to configure your lists do not load packages which redefines lists in beamer."