# A very compact list in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists

I would like to make a very compact list (e.g., `itemize`) in Beamer. [An identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968557/1100621) has been asked for an article-type document class; the answer uses the `enumitem` package, known to be [incompatible with Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer).

My question is: **How do I make the same compact list in the Beamer document class?**
As in the above linked question, I would like the list to have

- No whitespace before list
- No whitespace after list
- No whitespace between lines
- Less indent before the bullet points

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80103 (`\usepackage{paralist}`). But Ulrike's comment states: `You shouldn't load packages which redefines lists in beamer. This will destroy the beamer definitions. Use the commands of beamer to configure your lists.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve all four requirements in one shot, define your own `itemize` and don't touch Beamer's. In the following, I give an example of a `newenvironment` to replace Beamer's `itemize` and fulfill all your goals:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}$\bullet$~~ & #1
\end{tabularx}%
}    
\newenvironment{myitemize}{\par}{\par}     
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

normal text

normal text

\begin{myitemize}
    \myitem{first item}
    \myitem{second item}
    \myitem{third item}
\end{myitemize}

normal text

normal text 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the space before the bullet points:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

normal text

normal text

\begin{itemize}
\item Bar
\item Foo
\end{itemize}

normal text

normal text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For you other three requirements, please see [Adjust vertical space before enumerated list in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87251/36296).