# Text moving in beamer

Tags: beamer

How to move a text more to the left in a frame in beamer? because It seems that when compiling the text make a space to the right by default and I have tried the \hspace but didn't work (it only worked to move the text to the right but not to the left). I have written

```
                             \begin{frame}

                             \begin{itemize}

                             \item 1

                             \item 2

                             \end{itemize}

                             \end{frame}
```

Comment: I'd have thought that `\hspace` (or `\hspace*`) with a negative length, before the text, would work. What did you try exactly, can you show a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) demonstrating what you have and what you tried to do?

Comment: I have tried also \hspace with a negative length but nothing happened. I have written a usual slide nothing new example: \begin{frame} \begin{itemize} \item 1 \item 2 \end{itemize} \end{frame}

Comment: Please edit the question and include a complete example there, comments aren't really suited for a lot of code. At the beginning of a line you need `\hspace*{<length>}`, i.e. with an asterisk.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. okay

Comment: are you looking for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435822/36296 ? If this is not what you are looking for, please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and some sketch how the desired output should look like.

Comment: Or is it something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160825/modifying-margins-for-one-slide?

Comment: Notifications doesn't work when you have a space between the `@` and the username, so I wasn't notified of that comment. Should we close your question as a duplicate of that one then?